# android i am pointing on image by getting his x and y coordinate but these coordinate not support in iPhone

Tags: android

below is my code that i am getting image x and y coordinate  to exact match it iPhone devices

```
    fragmentImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            float density = getActivity().getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics().density;
            if (density == 4.0) {
                displayMetrixDensity = 640;
            }
            if (density == 3.0) {
                displayMetrixDensity = 480;
            }
            if (density == 2.0) {
                displayMetrixDensity = 320;
            }
            if (density == 1.5) {
                displayMetrixDensity = 160;
            }
            if (density == 1.0) {
                displayMetrixDensity = 160;
            }

            rowSize.x = (int) event.getRawX();
            rowSize.y = (int) event.getRawY();

            int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
            fragmentImageView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);

            rowSize.x = rowSize.x - viewCoords[0]; // viewCoords[0] is the X
                                                    // coordinate
            rowSize.y = rowSize.y - viewCoords[1]; // viewCoords[1] is the y
                                                    // coordinate

            // DisplayMetrics displayMetrics =
            // getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
            int dp = Math
                    .round(rowSize.x
                            / (displayMetrixDensity / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));
            int d = Math
                    .round(rowSize.y
                            / (displayMetrixDensity / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));

            rowSize.x = dp;
            rowSize.y = d;

        }
    });
```

these pixel also not support on big screen devices on android.

how can i solved it ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the question. What are you trying to do, what is not working and how iPhone is relevant to the issue?

Comment: actually i am pointing on image and save these coordinate  to database
but when i  set point from iPhone for those pixel i did't get an exact location

Comment: when i get image coordinate i get like 900 px but it not support on iPhone devices when i am pointing with same pixel

Comment: Well, it would have been really surprising if that worked between android and iOS devices - you have to take into consideration, scale factor of the image on the device and display pixel density in order to transform coordinates correctly. I would rather suggest you to try using vector images

Comment: i am new in android can u please help me to  how to use vector images